# How to work with Uri and QueryString in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Previously in old MVC and WebApi Request types (`HttpRequestBase` and `HttpRequestMessage`) had property `QueryString` of type `NameValueCollection`. It represent key-value pairs in request's query string.
Now in AspNet5 HttpRequest has `QueryString` property which type is `QueryString` struct. But it's just a wrapper around a string value. It doesn't have values, indexer, IEnumerable. Nothing.

How is it supposed to work with values in QS?

Also similar question about working with URI. Previously we had `HttpRequestBase.Url` and `HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri` of type `System.Uri`. Now just strings (PathBase, Path, QueryString). What's wrong with System.Uri? Why is it abandoned?

Comment: I think this fits as a suggestion on [HttpAbstractions](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions) repository rather than here.

Comment: @tugberk it's hard for me to tell in advance whether they refactored/redesigned things or just removed (everything is changed! :(). Asked here: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In beta-3, the `HttpRequest` also has a `Query` property, which is a new type, `IReadableStringCollection`.  This behaves almost identically to the `NameValueCollection`, as near as I can tell.  I'm using it my controllers through `Request.Query`.

Comment: Yes, it's the way to go. For additional info see https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/288

Actually `IReadableStringCollection` isn't quite identical as it's read only while `NameValueCollection` is read/write.